# Чат бот телеграмм не пересылает фото и документы

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Обычный текст спокойно переотправляется, а вот если приложить фото или документ то ничего не происходит

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def answer_q3(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

text = f"Тип обращения: {question_type}\n" \
       f"Имя : {message.from_user.first_name}\n" \
       f"Текст вопроса: \n{message.text}\n\n" \
       f"Дополнительно:"

if message.text is not None:
    await bot.send_message(**********, text)
elif message.photo is not None:
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=**********, photo=message.photo[-1].file_id,
                         caption=text)
elif message.document is not None:
    await bot.send_document(chat_id=**********, document=message.document.file_id,
                            caption=text)
await state.reset_state()
```

При этом, в дебаге есть сама фотка. с документом тоже самое (кусок дебага)

```
DEBUG:aiogram:Response for getUpdates: [200] "'{"ok":true,"result": 
 [{"update_id":********,\n"message":{"message_id":650,"from
{"id":*********,"is_bot":false,"first_name":
"**********","us 
ername":"******","language_code":"ru"},"chat": 
{"id":*******8,"first_name":"\**********","username":"********","type":"private"},"date":1695498029,"photo": 
[{"file_id":"AgACAgIAAxkBAAICimUPPy1l9go6cGzKwwY1BS2ToZJFAAKFzjEb1oh4SG9NFKpC- 
GGqAQADAgADcwADMAQ","file_unique_id":"AQADhc4xG9aIeEh4","file_size":565,
"width":90,"height":23},
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Возможно есть другой метод? как в телеботе? чтоб целиком переслать сообщение?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может заключаться в неправильном формате аргумента функции отправки.

Если я правильно понял по документации и коду, то там должен быть экземпляр класса InputFile, а не file_id. Можно прочитать подробнее по ссылке:

https://docs.aiogram.dev/uk_UA/latest/api/types/input_file.html#aiogram.types.input_file.InputFile

Comment: Это, к сожалению не помогло

Comment: @LestatCabrerra а аргументы приравняны к None в случае их отсутствия? Попробуй заменить все elif на if

Comment: Спасибо. Но это я уже тоже сделал. не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Решил половину проблемы:

С этой добавкой пересылаются и текст и фото. но только по отдельности (документы всё также не пересылаются)

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["text","objects", "photo", 'document'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Практически полностью решил свою проблему. Изменил метод отправки.

```
await bot.forward_message(**********, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Это пересылает (а не копирует) сообщение пользователя целиком и не важно есть там вложения или нет. Отправляет всё.

Это не совсем то, чего бы я хотел, но в целом наверное мне достаточно.

Если будут еще варианты, подкиньте пожалуйста